# Embedding and attaching double weapons to Warforged, specifically spiked chain

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, equipment, warforged, double-weapons

Regarding embedding and attaching weapons as warforged components, p. 114 of the Eberron Player's guide

> Weapons can be embedded or attached
> components. Two-handed weapons cannot be
> attached or embedded. A one-handed ranged or
> melee weapon can be attached to a hand, although
> you can still have only one weapon per hand, regardless
> of whether the weapon is held normally or
> attached. An attached weapon occupies your hand,
> and you must remove it to free the hand.
> A one-handed weapon that has the off-hand or
> light thrown property can be embedded.

Regarding double weapons, p. 10 of the Adventurer's Vault

> Wielding a double weapon is like wielding a weapon
> in each hand.

Additionally, almost every (if not every) double weapon in the game has the "off-hand" property.

Could a warforged attach, or even embed, a double weapon to one or both of his arms? If he can embed the item, could he theoretically retract the entirety of it within his arm? It's silly with most double weapons I could think of, but specifically I was thinking about the spiked chain, which gains the double weapon and off hand properties with the spiked chain training feat, p. 11 of Dragon Issue 372

> You gain proficiency with the spiked
> chain. You can treat the spiked chain as a double
> weapon and a light blade. As a double weapon, the
> spiked chain deals 2d4/2d4 damage, and it gains the
> off-hand property. For more on double weapons, see
> Adventurer’s Vault, page 10.

Could a warforged embed or attach one or both ends of a spiked chain, if he takes that feat? Could he embed the entirety of the chain in one of his arms, or just the end?

BONUS QUESTION:

I'm asking this because of a theoretical Warforged Melee Warlock I've been coming up with, who uses a spiked chain enchanted as a pact blade as his weapon to use Eldritch Strike, and use both ends of the pact blade spike chain for dual implement spellcaster. Could my warforged embed part of the chain in one arm and, while not use it to melee attack, still use it to cast spells as an implement? Regarding implements and embedding within warforged, from the WotC article [Playing Warforged](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dragon/364/364_Warforged.pdf):

> rods and
> wands can be embedded and hidden in your arm
> and still function, leaving your hands free for other
> tasks.

Now, obviously it does not say "pact blades" or "weapons functioning as an implement", but these are one-handed implements much like wands or rods. Is there a way of having a light blade function as an implement while still embedded within a warforged's arm?

Comment: The biggest thing I can see here boils down to the question: Are double weapons considered "Dual Wield" or "two-handed"? Since most double weapons are basically a stick with a weapon head on either side I'd have to consider them two handed... even the spiked chain would realistically be wielded with both hands but not technically be dual wielding because the chain connects both ends, and therefore makes it a two-hander. Since I couldn't find any mention of double weapons in the warforged embedded weapon literature, this is as far as my logic can take me without giving a wrong answer.

Comment: *Continued* The best you could probably hope for (unless someone has access to hidden rules in an obscure issue of Dragon) is to house rule this. I could see a relaxed DM saying that since the books don't specifically say double weapons can or can't be used as embedded/attached warforged components, one end of the spiked chain could be embedded on either arm, so that in combat you can extend a chain from either hand. Really wish I could help more and give an official answer, but conjecture is all I have with the lack of rules at my disposal (i have no dragon mags to comb through). Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes and yes.**

As you have practically embedded every relevant rule, I will only give the reasoning without citing the sources.
Spiked Chain Training makes it double weapon, double weapon means 2 one-handed weapons, one in each hand, and you can *attach* those. Embedding only works with some specific weapons, and the spiked chain is not one of those. It is not hidden, as only *embedded* components can be hidden.
Imagine it as a scarf, extending from one hand to the other over your neck.

Houseruling it so that it is embedded and hidden would not be overpowered however in my opinion, so talk to your DM.

Do not forget to add Dual Implement Spellcaster to your Eldrich Stike, as you make an arcane attack while wielding an implement in each hand.

There is one catch however, you have to enchant the item yourself, as a Pact Blade has to be a light blade, and Spiked Chain Training does not *make* Spiked Chain a light blade. You can enchant it, as you *treat* it as a light blade.

Comment: Only one question remains, why?

Comment: Can't think how you would you actually have this embedded in your body such a weapon. A sword can go in and out of the forearm, but that? does it run through your torso or does it exit your body and you wield it? Or is it outside but you don't use your hands anymore? This may be one of the reasons why double weapons are a no-no. I would houserule that no, spiked chains cannot be used. Whips yes.

Comment: This is the only double weapon that makes sense. Having a rod connecting your arms is just silly, like Double Axe. But Spiked Chain can go through your arms and torso, a windlass in the middle, pulling in one end and letting out the other (warforged only). Or wear it like a feather boa, for other races.

Comment: The only problem I can see is from the Playing Warforged PDF from Wizard's website (from Dragon magazine issue 364). On the subject of embedding weapons: "A dagger, shortsword, katar, or hand crossbow can be embedded. Up to five shurikens can be embedded in place of one of these items." Unfortunately it specifically dictates what weapons can be embedded. Something to consider perhaps?

Comment: @MC_Hambone: good point, changed the answer to _attach_.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short answer contributed by a non-member, since I've asked this question a few times and felt the need to answer.

I should note I'm going from a RULES-SPECIFIC response. Tehe run-the-chain-through-your-body thing is pretty cool; I just always imagined some aspect of the spiked chain required the length of chain travel between your hands for defensive purposes or something of the like (otherwise, why not make it dual flails?)

It's important to remember that a double weapon is considered a two-handed weapon for all intents and purposes, as WELL as being treated as a weapon in each hand. this means barbarians can gain effects from weapons that require both two-handedness and weilding a weapon in each hand, but unfortunately for your warforged, it also means you won't be able to retract, or even attach, your double-ender spiked chain, since you can't embed or attach two-handed wepons.

A spiked chain might not even really be what you're looking for, since spiked chains can't enchant as pact weapons to my knowledge. of course, if you were more intent on getting weapon reach without as much damage, you could take proficiency in whip, which can be both attached AND embedded, and has reach at the cost of damage. Slap one of those puppies in each hand and you essentially have a long flail emerging from each of your arms in a manner similar to spiked chain.

Comment: there's a difference (though subtle) between something being a two handed weapon, and a weapon in two hands. You can see this because certain double weapons have an end with the stout property that allows them to be wielded two handed.